# How to make a niche out of an object

Tags: modeling

**Hello!**

This is my very first post on this site, so please excuse me if something is not clear or the structure is bad.

Anyways, I am making a very detailed model of an engine, and I am having trouble with making this little niche or how to call it (highlighted - red color). As you can see in the picture, it's coming out of "top" part and smoothly joining the rounded tube.

---

[image]

---

Any ideas on how to make that? Your help would be so much appreciated!

**Best regards,
-T**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way: Once you've created your sphere, create a mesh with an edge that follow the profile of your excrescence. Once in top view use the *Knife Project* tool to project the profile on the sphere surface. Now join and delete some vertices, extrude up, close the top, create the small hole, etc... Maybe use the *Mirror* modifier to duplicate the shape all around, or duplicate this part 3 times, rotate it and paste it all around with the *Snap* (*Vertices* mode) + *Automatically Merge* options activated, and at the end create somme additional edges to sharp the edges.

[image]

Addendum:

[image]

Comment: The actual shape worked perfectly, but I am having trouble with smoothing it, the bottom edge looks so straight and hard, it's not looking like it's coming from the sphere smoothly, just like in the image I posted.

Comment: please share your file (fill the field with the URL of this page, then download): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6259" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6259/) here you go, I have a lot of versions, each from each part of modelling, so if this is too far from being successfully fixed, I can give you earlier versions.

Comment: select the big circle face and delete it, it's not good to have this kind of topology, select all your mesh and W > Remove Doubles because it looks like you've made an extrusion and forgotten to move it, select the whole rim, extrude inwards a bit, then extrude again so that you have some concentric circles, add additional edge loops to sharp the edges

Comment: (take a look at my edit)

Comment: Wow! I've never thought that someone could help me that much! This worked perfectly, looking absolutely gorgeous! Thank you so much! :-)